# Angular budgets throw error but files do not reach size

Tags: angular

In my Angular 8's `angular.json` file I have set an `initial` budget for production:

```
"production": {
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": true,
    "buildOptimizer": true,
    "fileReplacements": [{
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }],
    "budgets": [{
        "type": "initial",
        "maximumWarning": "1.5mb",
        "maximumError": "1.6mb"
    }],
    "serviceWorker": true
}
```

When I run `ng build --prod` the output errors:

[image: Console output]

However, none of the files tagged as `initial` have reached mentioned file size, neither alone nor together:

[image]

**What is happening? Why is this error being thrown?**

Note 1: Files get generated after removing budgets and running exactly same command, otherwise they don't get generated.

Note 2: Files generated seem to be duplicate, but that is Angular 8's differential loading (`es5`/`es2015`).

Note 3: Files generated don't even match in size with console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in older versions of the CLI. See issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15792 which was fixed by https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/16268. The bundle sizes are calculated post optimization given optimization is enabled.

Comment: Thanks Alan! This should be the accepted answer. I'll delete my post once it is unaccepted.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK budgeting targets initial budnle size, meaning that it counts all of `[initial]` marked files rather than each file separately which makes sense.

When specify "initial" it is *bundle* size **not** *individual file*'s size. Which makes sence because as you can see there is at least 6 files in an initial bundle and if they were `1.6 Mb` each users would probably be "fascinated" with loading time.

So, here you have at least 2 options that come into mind.

Fist - reduce the bundle size. 1.5 Mb vendor size minified is incredibly huge (IMHO).

Second - increase budgets. It used to be around 3 Mb in the past.

You can reference [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-size-budgets) for the budgets types.

Comment: The question is why the budget is exceeded when the bundle file size is nowhere near the budget. ("none of the files tagged as initial have reached mentioned file size, neither alone nor together")

Comment: Check the console output and you get the number. Why the actual output is defferent is out of SO concern. If it really is different then it must be in "issues" on GitHub. However, if I were you I would double check if I was looking into the right folder and the data is up to date (refresh the folder). Also it `KB` != `kB`. It's different measurement systems refer https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13815/files-size-units-kib-vs-kb-vs-kb

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas One more thing to mention. Regarding the "age" of the question it's worth considering updating the project to the latest version of framework since there are may be changes to this specific situation

Comment: No, why the output is different _is the question_, not "out of SO concern." If it is a bug, then the answer should be "it's is a bug".